# RecyclerView EditText value erase after scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

EditText input value erase after scrolling down and scrolling up.

I followed many tutorials but nothing worked for me, I tried to implement Textwatcher but I can't perfectly implement it.

Someone please help, I'm stuck with this problem. Please give me a solution if it had multiple edittext too.

here is my adapter code.

```
public class ClassTestMarkAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClassTestMarkAdapter.NviewHolder> {


    private Context mCtx;
    private List<ClassTestMarkModel> marklist;
    public ClassTestMarkAdapter(Context mCtx, List<ClassTestMarkModel> marklist) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.marklist = marklist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_test_mark_list,null);
        NviewHolder holder =new NviewHolder(v,new MyCustomEditTextListener());
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NviewHolder nviewHolder, int position) {
        ClassTestMarkModel markModel =marklist.get(position);
        nviewHolder.myCustomEditTextListener.updatePosition(nviewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        nviewHolder.wrText.setText(marklist[nviewHolder.getAdapterPosition()]);

        nviewHolder.stname.setText(markModel.getUserName());
        nviewHolder.stroll.setText(markModel.getRoll());
        nviewHolder.wrText.setText(markModel.getMarks());
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
        Long instituteID = prefs.getLong("InstituteID",0);
        final String inssid=String.valueOf(instituteID);
        final String subId = prefs.getString("subId", "");
        final String examids = prefs.getString("examidforct", "");
        final String sessionId = prefs.getString("sesId", "");
       final String cTMarkID=markModel.getcTMarkID();
       final String insCTID=markModel.getInsCTID();
       final String userID=markModel.getUserID();

        nviewHolder.btnMark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RequestQueue myRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx);
                String url = mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.baseUrlLocal)+"setExamCTMarks";
                final String xNon=nviewHolder.wrText.getText().toString();

                 Double wrsum= Double.valueOf(xNon);

                if (wrsum>0){
                    nviewHolder.btnMark.setText("Success!");
                    nviewHolder.btnMark.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#009000"));

                }


                StringRequest myStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(mCtx,"Success! Data Posted Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() { //Create an error listener to handle errors appropriately.
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(mCtx,"Error: Something Wrong...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> MyData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        MyData.put("CTMarkID", cTMarkID);
                        MyData.put("InsCTID", insCTID);
                        MyData.put("UserID",userID);
                        MyData.put("SessionID", sessionId);
                        MyData.put("SubjectID", subId);
                        MyData.put("ExamID", examids);
                        MyData.put("ObtainMarks",xNon);
                        MyData.put("InstituteID",inssid);
                        MyData.put("IsAbsent", "");
                        MyData.put("LoggedUserID", "123");
                        MyData.put("IP", "123");
                        return MyData;
                    }
                };
                myRequestQueue.add(myStringRequest);
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return marklist.size();
    }

    class NviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView stname, stroll;
        LinearLayout parentLayout;
        Button btnMark;
        EditText wrText;
       //String wrMark;
       public MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener;

        public NviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener) {
            super(itemView);

            stname =itemView.findViewById(R.id.clsmarkName);
            stroll =itemView.findViewById(R.id.clsmkRoll);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ctMarkList);
            btnMark =itemView.findViewById(R.id.clsmarkBtn);
            this.wrText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            this.myCustomEditTextListener = myCustomEditTextListener;
            this.wrText.addTextChangedListener(myCustomEditTextListener);

        }
    }
    private class MyCustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher {
        private int position;
        public void updatePosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       marklist[position] = s.toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your list item on text change using text watcher after setText to edit text.

Or Alternatively, For best practices use [two way data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) to overcome this issue.